# emberjs itemController breaks arrayControllers template

Tags: arrays, ember.js, controller

I have a list of posts I'm displaying in the usual way:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()

{{#each controller}}
  {{title}}
  {{body}}
{{/each}}
```

Now I was trying to add the capability to vote on posts. So I tried to add this to the PostController and reference it in the template like so:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
  itemController: 'post'
)

App.PostController = Ember.Controller.extend(
  upvote: ->
    # some code to upvote
)

{{#each controller}} # Note, also tried each post in controller
  {{title}}
  {{body}}
  <a {{action upvote}}>Upvote</a>
{{/each}}
```

This seems to have completely broken the existing template, however. The HTML and CSS is all read in, I can see the json is still being returned from the server, but the content is not being shown anymore. It seems that adding the itemController breaks the binding with the ArrayController.

I feel like I'm missing an essential step, but I'm not sure what it is and the API guide doesn't provide any additional direction.

Comment: As I can see you corrected the typo, does it still not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had PostController defined as a regular Controller and not an ObjectController, so it wasn't proxying the calls to the underlying model.

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  upvote: ->
    # some code to upvote
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you don't need the `itemController` (since it's not defined) you should remove it and the `upvote` event should be caught in the `PostsController`.

**Edit**

Your comment made me see that you have a typo, it should be:

```
App.PostController = Ember.Controller.extend(
  upvote: ->
  # some code to upvote
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what do you mean it's not defined?

Comment: @DVG, edited my answer, I guess you have a typo, your itemController should be `PostController` and not `PostsController`, makes sense?

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, I had the typo in the question, though it isn't in my code. The problem still persists, though. The especially curious thing is the correct number of rows are rendered on the page, all the divs for each individual item is rendered, but there isn't anything inside of them.

Comment: @DVG, just out of curiosity, did you try to define the `itemController` in the `each` itself, like `{{#each controller itemController="post"}}`?

Comment: Nope, it's defined in the ArrayController subclass